# nginx autoindex on for internal IP addresses only

Tags: nginx

I'm attempting to turn on indexing for just my internal IP range.

Some things that I have tested so far:

```
geo $internals {
    default 0;
    192.168.2.0/24 1;
}

location / {

        # Attempt 1, same error message.
        if ($internals) {
               autoindex on;
        }

        # Attempt 2, same error message.
        if ($remote_addr = "192.168.2.[2|254]") {
                autoindex on;
        }

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

No matter what I attempt, I always get:

```
Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] "autoindex" directive is not allowed here in ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the way to do this is to rewrite the URL to an internal one, and then use a separate location block according to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/nginxen/vy_VmMRFs40/iVex3S0UtvQJ).

So your config would look like:

```
http {

    geo $internals {
        default 0;
        192.168.2.0/24 1;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com www.example.com

    if ($internals) {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /post_redirect/$1 last;
    }

    location /post_redirect/ {
        internal;
        autoindex on;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }
}
```

And apparently the geo block goes in the http block not the server block.